# Jetpack Compose: elegantTextHeight in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I want to know what is android:elegantTextHeight attribute in Jetpack Compose

Comment: Hi @Raffly, this question and answer [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31821866/android-textview-what-does-eleganttextheight-do-api-21)  should help you understand this although not specific to Jetpack Compose.

Comment: Jetpack Compose doesn't _have_ `android:` attributes.  What exactly are you talking about?

Comment: well I mean what is the same function/property with android:elegantTextHeight in XML on jetpack compose

Comment: Follow this link on stackoverflow :https://stackoverflow.com/a/44570195/11395318

Answer (score 1):

According to [this description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31821866/android-textview-what-does-eleganttextheight-do-api-21), I think you are looking for a softWrap attribute.

> softWrap: Boolean = true

*Example:*

```
@Composable
Text(text = "Some text", softWrap = true)
```

Whether the text should break at soft line breaks. If false, the glyphs in the text will be positioned as if there was unlimited horizontal space. If softWrap is false, overflow and TextAlign may have unexpected effects.